# Cannot get full result while "grep file"

Tags: bash, grep, cygwin

I want to get the lines which contain "myString" in file "1.txt", and save the result to "2.txt". So I write these in a bash file:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep "myString" 1.txt > 2.txt
```

But I only got half of the "1.txt" grepped, it stopped with incomplete result in "2.txt". Using the commond instead of bash file didn't help.

I am doing this with cygwin64 on windows7.

Is there some terminator that would stop the "grep" commond, or a size limit on windows7, or something else?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: add a sample input file and show the output file you got while using this script... also, if you want a bash script, use `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks for the advice. I changed it into "bash", but it didn't help.. This didn't happen to every file, most of time it worked just well. The file couldn't be uploaded because it is a company file:) Maybe it was because of some Chinese characters? I would try it on a linux to see if it would work.

Comment: I should have given the link before itself.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve the idea is to find a way to replicate the problem as minimally as possible.. create sample files yourself and see if you can replicate the problem seen with your real usecase... then it would be easier to spot the issue

Comment: @Sundeep Thank you very much. I am almost new here, and not very familiar with the ways of asking questions, it helped a lot. And I have found the problem: because of some Chinese characters, the file was recognized as a binary file....orz

Comment: no problem, it is awesome that you tried and found the problem yourself :) you can add it as answer or delete the question...

Comment: I even didn't know I could do that lol...OK, I'll try, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Because of some Chinese characters, the file was recognized as a binary file.

It would be fine with "-a".

Also it worked just fine on Linux, with or without "-a".

So the windows7 or cygwin took a part in it too.

Thanks to @Sundeep for the help.

Comment: It is not a matter of Cygwin vs Linux. It is matter of file enconding and LANG used for your system. If LANG is `*.UTF-8` and the file is in a different encoding grep could match some byte sequence not valid in UTF-8 and assumes that the file is binary. Use `file <nomefile>` to identify the encoding.

Comment: Yes, the file is "Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines, with LF, NEL line terminators". But it did work well on Linux without "-a", while "-a" was necessary on Windows... should that be a matter of operating system?

Comment: I doubt the `locale` and/or the `grep `version are the same between the specific Linux and Cygwin you are using.

Comment: grep: 2.16 on Linux, 3.0 on cygwin. locale: en_US.UTF-8 on Linux, zh_CN.UTF-8 on cygwin. It it a little weird that it goes wrong on a system of Chinese characters...

Comment: use `iconv` to convert the file from current encoding to UTF8 and the problem will disappear. `Grep` changed some time ago and it is not anymore tolerant of wrong encoding detected as binary.